# How to do dimension reduction in Bag of Words for a Classification Model using Random Forest

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, nltk, random-forest, supervised-learning

I am using Text data Features along with other numerical features for  classification model.

How can I group similar bag of words together in a supervised classification Model. How I can group similar words after countvectorizing , I want reduce the dimension of bag of words .

My code

```
#Cleaning the Address Data
stopwords =nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
data['Clean_addr'] = data['Adj_Addr'].apply(lambda x:"".join([item for item in x if item not in stopwords]))
data['Clean_addr']=data['Clean_addr'].apply(lambda x:"".join([item for item in x if  not  item.isdigit()]))
data['Clean_addr']=data['Clean_addr'].apply(lambda x:"".join([item for item in x if item not in string.punctuation]))

#CountVectorizing the Address Data and fitting the sparse matrix to the Dataframe

cv = CountVectorizer( max_features = 1000,analyzer='word') 
cv_addr = cv.fit_transform(data.pop('Clean_addr'))
for i, col in enumerate(cv.get_feature_names()):
    data[col] = pd.SparseSeries(cv_addr[:, i].toarray().ravel(), fill_value=0)

#LabelEncoding -Converting Catergocial to Numerical
data['Resi'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(data['Resi'])
data['Resi_Area'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(data['Resi_Area'])
data['Product'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(data['Product'])
data['Phone_Type'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(data['Phone_Type'])
data['Co_Name_FLag'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(data['Co_Name_FLag'])

#Classification
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, Y, test_size=0.3,random_state =8)
rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=42)
X_train_res, y_train_res = rus.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)
rf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000,oob_score=True)

fit_rf=rf.fit(X_train_res,y_train_res)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to define a strategy of what do you mean by similar words. Do you mean that their length should be same or do you mean that abbreviations should be considered same as full forms etc. This in itself is a very broad problem and under active research. Maybe word2vec can help. word2vec will provide similar or close distance array values to similar words.

Comment: Or maybe you can create a dict of similar words and replace all occurences of other words in text with their representative word and then call TfidfVectorizer. But thats not recommended.

Comment: @VivekKumar, I am looking at abbreviations and also match limited & ltd  together

Comment: Yeah thats what I said. Its not as simple and straight forward. You need a collection of all such abbreviations which you can replace in your text.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reduce the diemension of your bag of words, you can use `SelectPercentile` from sklearn. Here is an exemple on Iris data :

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
import numpy
iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
selector = SelectPercentile(score_func=chi2, percentile=50)
X_reduced = selector.fit_transform(X, y)
```

You can easily extend it to a bag of words in your example:

```
cv = CountVectorizer( max_features = 1000,analyzer='word') 
cv_addr = cv.fit_transform(data.pop('Clean_addr'))
selector = SelectPercentile(score_func=chi2, percentile=50)
X_reduced = selector.fit_transform(cv_addr, Y)
```

After, that, you can do different trials to see which percentile works best, and eventually plot a score by percentile, but also plot the highly scored words with their term frequency associated, here is an example of such a bar plot :

[image]

Good luck.

Comment: Can this  handle  grouping similar words together in bag of words like Limited & Ltd  . Good & Nice etc.

Comment: mmh not really. If you want to group similar words either go for a tfidf weighting in a document-level or go for word embeddings. Chi square selection only scores words according to their discriminative power for classification.